# not able to pull content using CLI and SVS

Tags: sitecore-cli

I have installed the `Helix` example and I am trying to pull items from the Sitecore content tree using `CLI` and `SVS`. In both cases, I am getting an error,

`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

However, I was able to connect to the server by using

`dotnet sitecore login --auth https://id.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost --cm http://cm.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost --allow-write true`.

Any suggestion in this regard is highly appreciated.
I think this might be related to the port.

[image]

Phaneendra

Comment: Does your site run on `http` or `https`? It looks like you're trying to connect using `http`. Try changing to `https://cm.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost`

Comment: I am using https only I am able to open CM site. Issue is only connectivity from cli and svs.

Comment: Change `--cm parameter` in your command to `--cm https://cm.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost`. You're missing `s` after `http`. CLI is trying to connect to port 80 instead of 443

Comment: Yes, It worked after putting https... Thank you very much @MarekMusielak.

Comment: You're welcome @tpkphani . I converted my comment into an answer

Answer (score 0):

Change `--cm` parameter in your command to

```
--cm https://cm.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost
```

You're missing `s` after `http`.

CLI is trying to connect to port 80 instead of 443